# Stuck in Entity Framework due to Castle.Core

Tags: asp.net, aspnetboilerplate, castle, assembly-binding-redirect

I've followed the tutorial but it seems a bit outdated (ref. https://aspnetboilerplate.com/Pages/Documents/Articles/Introduction-With-AspNet-Core-And-Entity-Framework-Core-Part-1/index.html).

I build the program and then I do an `Update-Database`, but I get stuck on following error:

> Could not load file or assembly 'Castle.Core, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=407dd0808d44fbdc' or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)

First, I checked if I used the most recent version of .NET Core and then updated to latest (**dotnet-sdk-2.1.202-win-x64.exe**). Afterwards, I checked NuGet and I've got the most recent versions of `Castle.Core`, `Castle.Facilities.Logging` and `Castle.Windsor`.

I then tried following changes in the Entity Framework project, **App.config** file:

1. I removed `bindingRedirect` from `Castle.Core`, making it:

   ```
   <dependentAssembly>
       <assemblyIdentity name="Castle.Core" publicKeyToken="407dd0808d44fbdc" culture="neutral" />
   </dependentAssembly>
   ```
2. In NuGet, I've updated ABP and ABP Entity Framework from 3.8.1 to 3.8.2.
3. Reloaded the DLLs for Castle.

Comment: That's probably not an ASP.NET Core project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When I ALSO removed the `bindingRedirect` from `Castle.Core` in the Core project, it started to work.

```
<dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="Castle.Core" publicKeyToken="407dd0808d44fbdc" culture="neutral" />
</dependentAssembly>
```